# SQL to Linq multiple tables left outer join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, left-join

I have this query in SQL, and I want it to implement it in `LINQ using Entity Framework`, but how can I apply multiple tables left outer joins?

```
SELECT p.BookMastId as mastId
FROM BookMast p
left outer JOIN (SELECT y.BookMastId as Id, t.VrsnMastId as vrsn FROM BookReceiptMast t  
left outer JOIN BookReceiptDtl y 
on t.BookReceiptMastId = y.BookReceiptMastId) s 
on p.BookMastId = s.Id where s.vrsn = 2
```

Comment: You can do it similar to your SQL query, but it doesn't make sense because the last `WHERE` is basically turning all `LEFT OUTER` joins to `INNER`.

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use `from var in collection join in` syntax, something like this:

```cs
using(var cxt = new YourDataBaseContext()){
    var firstJoin = from t in cxt.BookReceiptMast
                    join y in cxt.BookReceiptDtl
                         on t.BookReceiptMastId equals y.BookReceiptMastId
                     into yTemp
                    from y in yTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = y != null ? y.BookMastId : 0,
                        vrsn = t.VrsnMastId
                    };

    var allTables = from p in cxt.BookMast
                    join s in firstJoin
                         on p.BookMastId equals s.Id
                         into sTemp
                    from s in sTemp
                    where s.vrsn == 2
                    select new
                    {
                        mastId = p.BookMastId
                    };
}
```

I hope it helps you.